# How can I send a value to uid using cloud functions in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new using firebase and I have a variable on the front-end side (Vue JS), how can I send this value to the UID? When I move to email it works.

```
exports.edit = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    admin
    .auth()
    .updateUser(uid, {
      email: data.email,
    })
    .then((userRecord) => {
      // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
      console.log('Successfully updated user', userRecord.toJSON());
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error updating user:', error);
    }); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you use callable functions, you already have the uid of the authenticated client(user) who calls that function and you can get it from:

`context.auth.uid`